# How can I add a tab to Tridion's Contact View?

Tags: tridion

SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

I'm trying to add a tabpage to the ContactView page in Tridion, using a GUI extension.
I've managed to add the extension to a ComponentView using:

```xml
<ext:tabpages>
  <ext:add>
    <ext:extension assignid="ContactWishlist" name="Wishlist Info"
                   insertbefore="InfoTab">
      <ext:control>/WebUI/Editors/ContactWishlist/ContactWishlist.ascx</ext:control>
      <ext:pagetype>ContactWishlist.WishlistInfo</ext:pagetype>
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>ContactWishlist.WishlistInfo</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>
      <ext:apply>
        <ext:view name="ComponentView">
          <ext:control id="MasterTabControl"/>
        </ext:view>
      </ext:apply>
    </ext:extension>
  </ext:add>
</ext:tabpages>
```

But when as I change 'ComponentView' into 'ContactView', nothing shows in front of the 'Info' tab within the Contact screen (no errors either).
Does Outbound Email require a different setup for GUI extensions?

Comment: Hi Reinder, welcome to  SO - nice to see the old faces coming out of the woodwork - I see you have an Area 51 account - Would you consider backing this proposal? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Comment: thought I already did. anyways, just committed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are few things you need to take into account:

- To extend any existing Editors, you need to create your own extension Editor. This extension Editor will contain all the needed files for your tab and configuration file, with resource groups and extension nodes.
- Indeed, OE is a different Editor. So you should carefully set the target Editor which you want to extend:

```xml
<ext:editorextensions>
   <ext:editorextension target="OEEditorName">...</ext:editorextension>
</ext:editorextensions>
```

Besides that View name and Control ID should be correctly set.

- You can specify path to your control as relative to the Editor where it defined. You just need to put "~" mark at the start:

```xml
<ext:control>~/ContactWishlist.ascx</ext:control>
```

It should be done because preceding path is configurable and could be different on different setups.

Comment: tnx, Boris! setting 'Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.Editor' as target in the <ext:editorextension> instead of 'CME' did the trick. I now have a 'Wishlist Info' tab in my contact screen

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Outbound Email Contact view is actually an extension itself, so you probably need to extend the OE editor rather than the standard CME one

Comment: tnx Chris, sounds reasonable. I tried adding my <ext:add> node to Tridions OEEditor.config, but get this error:
Element 'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions:add' cannot appear more than once if content model type is "all"
not sure what that means, other than that I'm diving deeper and deeper into the new GUI setup
I guess

Comment: correction: I moved my own <ext:extension> into OE configuration and also added my own <cfg:group> at the top.
No error, but still no tab too.

Answer (score 1):

The ext:view attribute sets the scope of when the Extension will try to be loaded.

Try changing the ext:view ComponentView to * and see if it loads.  The Tridion docs don't have a definitive list of Views and we can guess from the list in the folder Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views.

Comment: hey Robert, tnx!
no luck on setting the view to '*'. The contact screen has no extra tab, and the component screen is completely broken.
I'm starting to doubt whether it's possible, since OE's folder has a lot of aspx 'Views' pages, where the tabs are written out directly in the source. Like \Tridion\Outbound Email\Editors\Views\Contact.aspx

Comment: but if i remove it from the OEEditor.config and place it as a regular tab inside System.config for 'ComponentView', it works fine...

Comment: Do you have an InfoTab?  Did you try enabling GUI logging?  Look for tracing in this post http://www.curlette.com/?p=580  Don't worry about breaking the GUI when building an extension - I usually break it for 90% of the time until that last hour when it all starts working.

Comment: I managed to get the Trace running, but get a lot of 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException' errors now. What should I look for in the trace? The InfoTab is showing, by the way